# How to convert "2017-01-09T11:00:00.000Z" into Date in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdate, alamofire, nsdateformatter

My problem is that the date is nil.

My code looks like

```
print(article_date) // output "2017-01-09T11:00:00.000Z" as string
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date : Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: article_date!)
print("date: \(date)")
```

I've tried a few formatters like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", but nothing worked.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to set both `.SSS` and `Z` with your `dateFormat`, so your `dateFormat` should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-09T11:00:00.000Z")
print("date: \(date)")
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.